# HG rebase using bookmark names

Tags: git, mercurial

In git we can run commands like:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout mybranch
git rebase master
```

which will take the commits made on `mybranch` and rebase them onto the updated master. ie: linearlize the commits of `master` and `mybranch`. I know that there's a rebase extension for mercurial but it seems it does rebasing based on revision numbers instead of bookmark names. Is there a way to make it work with bookmark names?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `hg rebase` command accepts not only revision numbers, but also bookmarks, tags, branch names, revsets; basically, anything that can be used to refer to a revision (like practically any command that takes `REV` arguments). No Mercurial command that I can think of is limited to revision numbers only (see `hg help revisions` and `hg help revsets`).

That said, while you can operate Mercurial entirely in a Git-like fashion (and if that's what you are most comfortable with, you should definitely stick with it), note that linearizing history is a Git peculiarity, because Git's history is largely anonymous. Version control systems with named branches (e.g. Mercurial or Fossil) or with hierarchical logs (e.g. Bazaar) do not really need to linearize history.

Rebase can, of course, still be useful for other purposes, or if you prefer to use bookmarks instead of named branches.